# Where is my Beta badge?

Tags: support, badges

So, the description for the Beta badge says that one must "Actively participated in the private beta".

Is Programmers not a "private" beta or something? Because I'm wondering what all would actually be needed to achieve this badge otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The private beta for Programmers lasted for 7 days immediately following the conclusion of the commitment period. It is unattainable now. We're currently in the public beta period.

Answer (score 1):

But you can still fulfill your Area 51 commitment to the site -- assuming you [committed to the site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352?phase=commitment) -- for a [badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/210/upholder) on http://area51.stackexchange.com