# Where is my Beta badge?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is my Beta badge?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/where-is-my-beta-badge)

So I know from Mark Trapp's [answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/where-is-my-beta-badge/529#529) to [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/where-is-my-beta-badge) that

> The private beta for Programmers
>   lasted for 7 days immediately
>   following the conclusion of the
>   commitment period. It is unattainable
>   now. We're currently in the public
>   beta period.

So from I gather the Private Beta started on 9/1/2010. [My oldest answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/775/what-is-the-ideal-mix-of-senior-to-junior-developers-on-a-team/788#788) is from 9/3/2010. So I had some activity in the first week.

Obviously I wasn't active enough. Any ideas what more I needed?

Comment: It seems this is the definitive answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users/19#19

Comment: Oddly It would seem I do meet the three bronze badge rule. Won't be able to prove it until this site ends the beta and shows up on odata

Comment: Spoke to soon. Jeff's comment on his answer is that the requirements are a bit more strict now. He should edit his answer.

Comment: That question and answer referred to the beta periods of Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User which were handled a lot differently to the new SE 2.0 sites. Here the requirement is 10 posts (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Just from my intial read, the Beta Badge description says

> Actively participated in the private beta

I'm pretty sure that one answer is not actively participating.  But to your point, I don't know what number of questions/answers is.